# User control property not visible when accessed from outside in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, user-controls

**Situation**

- I have a WinForm `Form1` with two User Controls (called `startControl` and `resultsControl`) added
- My `resultsControl` has a `DataGridView` called `dataGridView1` which has been added by the Designer
- My `startControl` has a `DataTable` called `dt`

**Goal**

- Bind the `DataTable` from `startControl` to my `DataGridView` in `resultsControl`

What I've tried is to expose my `dataGridView1` from `resultsControl` as a property and access it's `DataSource` in `startControl` but for some reason the exposed property isn't visible to me in neither `Form1` nor `startControl`.

**Code**

```
public partial class resultsControl : UserControl
{
    public resultsControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [PropertyTab("Data"), Description("Test"), Category("Misc"), Browsable(true)]
    public DataGridView dgvParameter
    {
        get
        {
            return this.dataGridView1;
        }
        set
        {
            this.dataGridView1 = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I can't seem to access my `dataGridView1` by using `resultsControl.dgvParameter` - what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

As pointed out I need to work with an instance of `resultsControl`. I already created an instance of `resultsControl` in my `Form1` - that means I just need to access it from my `startControl` user control, right?

My first guess would've been to expose another property in `Form1` or is there another way to access it from my (parent) form?

**Code**

```
public partial class homeForm : Form
    {
        public homeForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnDashStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            startControl control = new startControl();
            ShowControl(control);
        }

        private void btnDashResults_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            resultsControl control = new resultsControl();

            ShowControl(control);
        }

        public void ShowControl (Control control)
        {
            containerPanel.Controls.Clear();

            control.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            control.BringToFront();
            control.Focus();
            containerPanel.Controls.Add(control); 
        }
}
```

Comment: I just noticed another flaw - whenever I click on `btnDashStart_Click` it resets my whole page since a new instance is created.I probably should've declared the `UserControls` inside the class (?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the *instance* of `resultsControl` because your `dgvParameter` is not a `static` property.

Go into the designer view and click on your control.  In the "Properties" window, look at the 'Name' property.  That's the name of your instance, e.g. `resultsControl1`.  Now you can use `resultsControl1.dgvParameter` in your code.

By the way, you should adhere to naming conventions, i.e. properties and classes should be named using UpperCamelCase.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Is it wise to make `dgvParameter` `static` since I'd be using one instance of `DataGridView` for my whole program only? I am not entirely sure if I should be creating a new Instance of my `resultsControl` since I already create an instance in my `Form1`? I am not sure at all, I'll edit my post with the `Form1` code

Comment: No, you should always work with the instances of your classes -- controls included -- at least until you know a little more about OO programming concepts.

Comment: I updated my question with additional code for clarification. I can access my `dgvParameter` from my  `homeForm` but is it possible to access `dgvParameter` directly from `startControl`? And I will keep the naming conventions in mind, thank you!